# How to get the variable passed through the function JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the function

```
function addCategory(category) {
$('#category_choice').append($('#!the variable "category" has to go in here!'));
$('#feed_submit_categories').hide();
}
```

The "category" variable sends the id of the element that has to be appended. How can I insert the "category" var into the function? In PHP it is much easier having $var_name tags... But here, I have no idea as to how to include it.

Comment: You're looking for string concatenation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function addCategory(category) {
    $('#category_choice').append($('#'+category));
    $('#feed_submit_categories').hide();
}
```

Simple example of concatenation ( variables, string ):

```
var h = "Hello";
var w = "World!";

alert( h+w );            // HelloWorld!
alert( h+' '+w);         // Hello World!
alert( h+' my dear '+w); // Hello my dear World!
```

jQuery selector can use `string` to represent literally an element ID selector:

```
$('#element')
```

that means you keep as string what you need and you concatenate a variable to it:

```
var elName = "element"; // string variable
$('#'+ elName) // same as: $('#element')
```

---

If you need to append every time a new fresh element do like:

```
$('#category_choice').append('<div id="'+category+'" />');
```

just make sure not to duplicate your elements `ID` for ID has to be unique per page element.

Comment: Thank you! *random text to cover the minimum characters in comment box*

Comment: thanx a million! I was doing it this way (but wasn't able to pass the "category" item), but than I decided to just copy the div I want to append, but it started consuming them =)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#category_choice').append($('#'+category));
```

jQuery selectors are just strings that are evaluated, you can generate a string following basic Javascript rules.

For example :

```
var iAmString = "#"+category;
$(iAmString)  //<-- using string var as a selector
```

Comment: is there a way to make a copy of the div I am appending? Because I am echoing categories with PHP, and every time I run this function, it takes away the div...

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
function addCategory(category) {
  $('#category_choice').append( $('#'+category) );
  $('#feed_submit_categories').hide();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! *random text to cover the minimum characters in comment box*